# C# WPF Visualiser: Reading data from Serial Port

Tags: c#, wpf, arm

I'm trying to build a WPF application that would read data from Serial Port that is reading data from an MPU6050 connected to a ARM NUCLEO-F303K8. I have managed to get the code to a point where it is now showing in the GUI the value of the Pitch and Roll however, it is still showing invalid Data in the output box. I think the likely culprit is that I am using "ThisThread::sleepfor" and "\n\r" and it is causing some issue with how the WPF program reads from the Serial.

Here is the relevant mbed code:

```
// Print values to serial console - Now includes Time
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
             
             // Seperated by comma for CSV and C# visualiser
            "%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f\n\r",
            int (elapsed_time / 1h), int((elapsed_time % 1h) / 1min), int((elapsed_time % 1min) / 1s), int((elapsed_time % 1s) / 1ms),
            pitch, roll, temperature);

        printf("%s", buffer);

        ThisThread::sleep_for(100ms); // Delay to read data
```

In my WPF xaml.cs file I have the following code for the data display in the GUI:

```
  private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
  { 
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        try
    {
        // Ensure there's data to read
        if (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
            serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            data = data.Trim();

            string[] items = data.Split(','); // Split to comma separated
            if (items.Length == 4) // Check for 4 items
            {
                op_time = float.Parse(items[0]);
                roll = float.Parse(items[1]);
                pitch = float.Parse(items[2]);
                temperature = float.Parse(items[3]);

                txtPitchValue.Content = pitch.ToString("0.00");
                txtRollValue.Content = roll.ToString("0.00");
            }
            else
            {
                txtOutput.Text = "Invalid data format";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = "Error processing data from serial port: " + ex.Message;
    }
}));


}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Cheers

Comment: `float.Parse` will obviously not parse a timestamp string created by `%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d`. You should have seen an exception. Besides that, you are writing first pitch, then roll, but reading first roll, then pitch.

Comment: There is no guarantee that all of the data is received at the same time.  It is perfectly possible that the event is raised once for each byte received. You probably only want to read data if you are sure you have the full message. Or read the data and put it in an intermediate buffer, and only do the parsing once the complete message is received.

Comment: I would also use the return value from `read` to determine the number of bytes read, I would not trust that it always returns `BytesToRead`.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've managed to figure it out. Thanks guys for your help. At first Clemens, I thought what do you mean Parse is wrong and then was like "ohhh doh thats why" thanks.

JonasH, thank you for that explanation it helped in understanding BytesToRead, I am now using ReadExisting() instead to find available data.

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // sender is SerialPort and related data event
{
                                                                            // Dispatcher needs to be run in current Application 
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>                      // WPF requires we use UI thread for updates to UI elements
{
try
{
string receivedData = serialPort.ReadExisting(); // Instead of using BytesToRead we use ReadExisting to read available data
receivedDataBuffer.Append(receivedData);         // Using StringBuilder instead of Read() to gather new data with incomplete data
                                                 // Partial monitoring to avoid "invalid data format" error.


string buffer = receivedDataBuffer.ToString();
if (buffer.Contains("\n"))
{
    
    string[] lines = buffer.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None); 
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && line.Contains(",")) // Ignores empty and lines containing commas
        {
            string[] items = line.Split(','); // split line string into items based on comma
            if (items.Length == 4) // Must be 4 items
            {
                timestamp = items[0]; // Keep as string 
                pitch = float.Parse(items[1]); // Switched to pitch
                roll = float.Parse(items[2]);  // Switched to roll
                temperature = float.Parse(items[3]);
                if (txtPitchValue != null && txtRollValue != null)
                {
                    txtPitchValue.Content = pitch.ToString("0.00");
                    txtRollValue.Content = roll.ToString("0.00");
                }
                receivedDataBuffer.Clear(); // Clears buffer
            } else
              {
                txtOutput.Text = "Invalid data format";
              }
        } 
    }
}
} catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = "Error processing data from serial port: " + ex.Message;
    }
}));
}
```